# Use PHP to get Linkedin followers

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have Googled and searched Stackoverflow along with looking at Linkedin but I can't seem to find out how to get the number of followers on Linkedin using PHP.

URL: http://www.linkedin.com/company/COMPANY NAME
Followers: (X,XXX followers)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [linkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis). There should be everything you need. Just call the API with simple get or post requests from your PHP and thats it.

This particular link should help you: `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/following/companies`